# SVG polyline/polygon's points dom value is different from points attribute value

Tags: svg

See this svg code

```
<polyline id="poly" points="163.2 100 163.2 200"
     stroke-width="1" fill="none" stroke="red"></polyline>
```

and this javascript code

```
var poly = document.getElementById('poly');
console.log(poly.points.getItem(0).x);
```

will get **163.1999969482422**. not the expected **163.2**

and (163.2 == 163.1999969482422) is **false** in javascript.

I tested in chrome and firefox.

Is this a bug or I must use `poly.getAttribute('points')` and parse the attribute value string to array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve speed and performance, most UAs encode polyline points as IEEE-754 format floats. 163.2 cannot be exactly represented in binary in the 32 bit IEEE-754 format. [The nearest 32 bit IEEE-754 value](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to 163.2 is 163.1999969482422 as you've discovered by experimentation. And that's how the value is stored internally.

javascript however stores numbers in 64 bit IEEE-754 binary which allows greater precision so the nearest 32 bit value does not match the nearest 64 bit value exactly.